Difference between Principled BSDF Anisotropy and Glossy Anisotropy
Does anyone know why the "Anisotropy" setting in the Principled BSDF seems capped at ~69% (and rotated 90°) compared to what you get out of the Glossy BSDF and is there anything I can do about it?
The fact that an anisotropy of "1" in the Principled BSDF seems equal to an anisotropy of ln(2) in the Glossy BSDF seems too good of a coincidence to some arbitrary magic number so I'm guessing there's a reason for it...
P.S. This is using Cycles in Blender 4.3 on Linux.
Glossy anisotropy set to ln(2)

Glossy anisotropy set to 1

This answer is without guarantee, just personal experience and testing: you are quite close with your ln(2), however as you can see you also have to change the Rotation in the Glossy BSDF to get a similar result compared to the Principled BSDF.
If you want both nodes to give a similar result (similar, not same because I think it does not always look exactly the same) while keeping the same Rotation value in the Glossy BSDF as the Anisotropic Rotation in the Principled BSDF, then you have to multiply ln(2) with the negative Anisotropic value of the Principled BSDF.
So if you set
Principled BSDF:
$$\begin{split}\text{Anisotropic} & = x \quad & | \quad x \in [0,1] \\
\text{Anisotropic Rotation} & = y \quad & | \quad y \in [0,1]
\end{split}$$
then you need
Glossy BSDF:
$$\begin{split}\text{Anisotropy} & = -x \cdot \ln{2}\\
\text{Rotation} & = y
\end{split}$$
Examples:
First of all, simply using Anisotropic = 1 and Anisotropic Rotation = 0 in the Principled BSDF. So with the above statements, this means in the Glossy BSDF I have to set the Anisotropy to -ln(2) and leave the Rotation at 0. Note that the Roughness is in both nodes the same and also the light scattering distribution in both is set to Multiscatter GGX, different distributions give different results, and while the Glossy BSDF has four methods to choose from, the Principled BSDF only has two of them.

Now if I slightly change the rotation on both to 0.1:

And now changing the Anisotropic value to 0.75, which means in the Glossy BSDF the Anisotropy value has to be changed to -0.75 · ln(2) to look similar. I also changed the rotation again to 0.9, but what you might already which is why I said similar instead of same result: there is a slight difference, depending on the value and rotation angle this can be more or less obvious. But with ln(2) I get the closest results, maybe a little less than 2 like 1.9 - but that's the thing with experimenting: I do not know what the actual calculation behind it is, so I can only estimate values.

